# If $\sum\limits_{t=1}^{\infty}R_t$ is finite with $R_t\geq 0$, does $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}R_t=0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

This question arises from my study of economic models with an infinite time horizon in which production is constrained by a finite initial stock of a non-renewable resource.

Given $\sum\limits_{t=1}^{\infty}R_t = S$ where $S$ is finite and $R_t\geq 0\,\forall t$, can it be inferred that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}R_t=0$, and if so how can this be proved?

My thoughts: From the definition of a limit and given $R_t\geq 0$, we require that for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists $k \in \mathbf{N}$ such that $R_t<\epsilon\, \forall t>k$.  If $R_t$ decreases monotonically it seems obvious that this must hold.  However, the fact that the sum is finite does not require $R_t$ to decrease monotonically.  It could be that $R_t=0$ for most $t$ and is positive only for occasional $t$ at widely spaced intervals.  In that case the result doesn't seem obvious.

Comment: If a series is convergent its terms must tend to $0$.

Comment: To be fair, this is true only if you are summing with a Cauchy method. If you were to use Cesaro criterion to sum, this result wouldn't hold.

Comment: This fact (without the redundant assumption $R_t \ge 0$) should be in every beginning calculus textbook.  Congratulations if you discovered it without ever taking such a course!

Comment: @DavideTrono In the application I am interested in, $R_t$ is the quantity of a resource used in period $t$.  Is there any reason why the Cauchy method - which to me seems much more natural than the Cesaro method - should not be used to obtain the sum to infinity?

Comment: @AdamBailey I don't think so. But if one day you will end up with a similar concept (infinite sum of resources) which, by any unluck, diverges, then maybe using stronger methods than Cauchys one could be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S_N:= \sum^N R_k$ converges, so is a Cauchy sequence, so $|\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}R_k-\sum_{k=1}^{n}R_k|= |R_{n+1}|$   becomes arbitrarily small.

This also
shows that the assumption $R_k\ge 0$ can be omitted.